# Is there any way to auto fold PHP docblocs in sublime

Tags: php, python, formatting, sublimetext2, code-folding

Is there an easy way that will automatically fold all docblocs for PHP/JS/HTML/CSS ? 
The docblocs in my code can be quite long, it makes navigating the code quite difficult.

Is there anyway to do this simply with a preference setting or a simple plugin? I am  not familiar to Python and sublime configuration options much, any solution short of writing my own plugin will be great

Comment: I suggest asking at http://www.reddit.com/r/sublimetext/ , they usually know.

Comment: thanks I will try there, I would have thought SO is the best place to ask programming questions!